# Ubuntu can not boot due to disk space full

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, virtualbox, grub

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on a Virtualbox in a portable SSD, but I was not paying attention that the disk space is running out. Now from the Virtual box, it can not enter the Ubuntu GUI. The grub is OK, however, I can not enter the recovery mode, which would pump up 'Fail to Start kernel modules'.

the grub command line is ok, but I do not know what to do next.

I would appreciate it if anyone can give me a hint since the file is really important.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could boot from a live CD and try to mount the full partition. Once it is mounted, you can delete the unnecessary files with the [rm](https://learn.akamai.com/en-us/webhelp/netstorage/netstorage-user-guide/GUID-BE143989-A94E-4AAC-86B3-0A5651D6C460.html#:%7E:text=Use%20this%20command%20to%20delete,complete%20path%20to%20be%20deleted.) command (be careful with the recursive option).

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a VM you should have a backup/snapshot from before the issue but if not you may still get away with it by

1. Increasing the virtual drive size then
2. Boot a live session (add Ubuntu ISO again) and use Gparted to expand the partition or partitions that now are low on space.
3. Try booting normally and if successful then correct the issue leading to the low space.